# Sails/Waterlock password reset flow

Tags: ember.js, passwords, sails.js, reset, waterlock

G'day all,

Does anyone have any experience with the Waterlock flow for passsword resets? I've hit a wall which I can see a work-around for, but it seems really in-elegant, so I'm probably missing something.

When I send through an auth/reset POST with an email element, the system proceeds to shoot the email out as planned.

When I then submit the received link in a POST request, with a password element, I see a "404" response.

**HOWEVER**

If I submit that link as a GET request first, and then submit the POST it works.

When I look into the waterlock-local-auth source, the reset POST action is testing for the presence of a decrypted token in the request object before allowing it to proceed.

**SO**

Either I code my front end to send a get request (which doesn't respond properly) and then resubmit as a POST, or I go in and hack the waterlock-local-auth code to include a decode of the token (which is what I'm thinking is the most elegant solution).

Any clues?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I have got a similar problem, but I use angularjs as my frontend. This discussion thread is very helpful:

https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/issues/7

Basically, you are expected to submit a GET request to the url received in the password reset email. After you click the link with the token, you will find in your database that a new ResetToken record has been created and the value in the token column is exactly the one you see in the url. Then you should be redirected to the `forwardUrl` in waterlock.js setting, where there should be a form or anything that can make you post to:

http://yourdomain.com/auth/reset?password=newpassword

Then the password is reset and the ResetToken record will be removed from your database.

If you look at the `handlePost` function here:

https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/blob/master/lib/controllers/actions/reset.js#L68

This can explain why POSTing to the url sent to you in the reset password email returns 404. The `resetToken` must exist in session already in order that `issuePasswordReset` to be invoked. And the only place to set `req.session.resetToken` is within `validateToken` method:

https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/blob/master/lib/controllers/actions/reset.js#L188

So you need a get request first. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, but I still seem to be getting to the post handler with a null token in the session. Currently trying to see why that's the case, and at the same time adding support for recaptcha in the flow...

Comment: Two questions: (1) have you set the ```tokens``` in ```passwordReset``` to be true?  (2) have you upgraded the waterlock and waterlock-local-auth to the latest version (0.1.2-rc1 at the moment) ? The sending email function was broken in the old version.